# Current sensing in logarithm-scale (with voltage output proportional to current)

Tags: current-measurement

I need to sense current in a small range: from *0mA* to *150mA*, but with a device which can withstand a much higher current range up to *5A*.

Output voltage shall be easy-to-read with a standard A/D converter (which is found in common microcontrollers).

Also, the whole PCB shall be super tiny, can't afford much more than this current sensing IC and a microcontroller with very limited discrete components.

For similar purposes I've always used an IC from Allegro, the [ACS712](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/0712.pdf), which is a

> Fully Integrated, Hall Effect-Based Linear Current Sensor
> with 2.1 kVRMS Voltage Isolation and a Low-Resistance Current Conductor

However, it's sensitivity is too low for my purposes now, even the best case its output sensitivity is around **185mV/A** (typical).

I need to sense 50mA current flow, which in this case would be 185/20 = **9mV**. I guess this is very low to use with a standard A/D converter.

Yes, I could amplify ACS712's output, but I need to spare on components, and 9mV is I believe not that easily amplifiable.

I think I need to find a *Fully Integrated, Hall Effect-Based Logarithm Current Sensor*.

Can you recommend me some parts with this feature? I would be happy to get a nicely recognizable range from 0mA to 150mA, beyond that point, output does not really matter.

NB: Preferrably something which is available and on stock. :)

Comment: Sorry, recommendations for specific products are off-topic for this site.

Comment: What do you mean logarithm scale? ACS712 is linear scale. A diode has the property that Vf is proportional to the logarithm of the current. But I am guessing you can't or don't want to tolerate a full diode drop?

Comment: Logarithm scale means that in lower levels (below 1A for example) voltage output goes from 0-50% of the range. And the higher levels (above 1A-5A) goes from 50%-100%. This is not fully logarithm - I know. Just I'm looking for something which is extremely high sensitive in lower range while can withstand high currents too.

Comment: I'm measuring DC currents only.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a resistive current sensor (high side), which works great.

I got the idea out of an old article some years ago

[image: current sensor circuit]

Here you can use a resistor which can carry 5A for as long as you want (given a proper thermal design), the few transistors can be quite small.

Original source:

**Circuit senses high-side current**
by Bob Bell and Jim Hill, On Semiconductor, Phoenix, AZ
Original publication was EDNMag [www.ednmag.com](http://www.ednmag.com) (no longer active)
March 1, 2001
Edited by Bill Travis and Anne Watson Swager

Now available at: https://www.edn.com/circuit-senses-high-side-current/

(PDF file containing the schematic and more details also [available on archive.org here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160614185614/https://m.eet.com/media/1145854/22017-30101di.pdf).)

Comment: Thx for the Edit... wasn't aware last night that edn and that article still exist...

Comment: [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVcSH.png) a similar circuit for HV current sense that I've used. Partly derived from an article, partly mutation. Very nice in operation.

Comment: Thank you. I'm very limited in space, and the circuit shall be guarding a battery, so I'd avoid any series resistance if possible. Limited in space = prefer if I can solve this with one IC, instead of one IC + 7 transistors + 9 resistors :)

Comment: the ACS712 5A Type  for example shows a example how to boost sensitivity up to 600mv/A. This would be ~30mV at 0,5A. You should be able to use a 8-bit ADC for evaluation. But again - you need some more external parts to build the booster.

Comment: Maybe you can get something like Infineons TLE4997E2 to work, but event then you need something to boost your mag. field. See Field Concentrators in https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Current_Sensing_Rev.1.1.pdf?fileId=db3a304332d040720132d939503e5f17 for example. That seems feasible to me.

Comment: Also found this... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96759/why-dont-hall-effect-current-sensors-exist-for-low-currents