# Type of transformer needed to measure 4-20mA process current?

Tags: transformer, current-measurement, measurement, component-selection, current-transformer

I occasionally work with 4-20mA process signals and need to read the current value flowing through the wire.  I now use a standard Fluke 17B+ and must disconnect the loop and add the meter in series to read the current value.

I realize 4-20mA process clamp meters are available for purchase, but in this case I was thinking of learning something by making my own non-invasive clamp meter to read these levels.

However, I'm not sure what transformer to use.

Clamp-on split core transformers are readily available, but they are usually designed for at least 0-1 A through the primary, which equates to 0-1V on the secondary.

It seems that in order to detect small signals such as the 4-20mA range without being overpowered by noise on the secondary, the ratio would need to closer to unity (1:1).

Does anyone have any insight into what type of split core transformer could be used in this application?  I have not been able to find 1:1 split core transformers yet, but maybe it would be simple to make this by hand or re-work a standard split core component by adding windings?

Thanks for any pointers toward the correct component.

Comment: A normal transformer won’t capture and DC signal, which 4-20 mA is. You need a Hall effect sensor or LEM module.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96759/why-dont-hall-effect-current-sensors-exist-for-low-currents

Comment: You would need a Hall sensor to get down to DC, but I don't think you can do this practically with a single-turn primary at 20mA FS. More like 1,000 or even 10,000 turns (depending on whether you can zero before each measurement). And preferably closed-loop since accuracy and linearity is important- that means another coil for feedback.